# Change the same field from all the tables from a particular database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Suppose I have a database `sitedb` and in that I have 20 tables and a primary key(say `uid`) for one table is used in other tables as dependencies.
`uid` is of type `int` with length `10`. Lets say that the number of entries in the table is full and I need to increase the capacity of the `uid` to the length `11`.
Is it right to do so? What will happen to the related tables and how will it affect the relation?
What if I change the value of `uid` in all the tables to length `11`. Is there a tool which will allow me to check and change the value of every related `uid` in all the tables in the database? Updates?

Comment: `int(10)` does not mean capacity `10`. It means "allocate at least 10 chars for output."

Comment: `int(10) unsigned` means you can store numbers from `0` up to `2^32 - 1` which is a bit more than 4-billion. Is your table really full?

Comment: @ypercube no it isn't ;-) actually I thought about the requirement of a million user site, and thought of to put it in a scenario; so asked this question.
does it make any difference if I change it to `int(11)`?

Comment: No, if your column is `UNSIGNED` (as the `int(10)` suggests), you can modify it to `int(11) unsigned`. This has no effect on the data that is or can be stored inside the column and no effect on the Foreign Key dependencies.

Comment: But it's useless, makes no difference to do so.

Comment: looking at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html), it means that I can store `0` to `4294967295` unsigned integer values in my column.
then would you please explain the significance of the length of the length of the `int` in the answer of this question. I'll be happy to accept it :-)

Comment: Read this: [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify column by name(s):
you can also use any SQL `Where`, such as column_name in (...) or using other columns in 
 `information_schema.columns` table.

```
select  concat('alter table ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' change column ... ;') from information_schema.columns  where column_name='r_id'
```

use group_concat or similar and just copy/paste.